# Unable to refresh tableview using EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, pull-to-refresh

I use  [RSSReader Version 2.0 with UITabBarController](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/rssreader-version-2-0-with-uitabbarcontroller.php) in my project. Tried to add a tableview update feature "pull to refresh" by [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh).

I added 4 files to the project:

- EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h
- EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m
- PullToRefreshTableViewController.h
- PullToRefreshTableViewController.m

My ViewController.h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RSSParser.h"
#import "PullToRefreshTableViewController.h"

@interface RSSListViewController : PullToRefreshTableViewController <RSSParserDelegate> {
    RSSParser * _rssParser;

}



- (id)initWithRSSURL:(NSString *)rssURL;

- (void)startActivity:(id)sender;

- (void)stopActivity:(id)sender;


@end
```

and in ViewController.m I added this lines:

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource{
[super performSelector:@selector(dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

}

- (void)dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData{
    [refreshHeaderView setCurrentDate]; 
    [super dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**The update process begins, but the information doesn't get updated.**

[image]

## I'm new to xcode, can anyone help with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Is "dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData" called?

Comment: In "ViewController.m". It successfully completes the process, but the information is not updated.

Comment: Is any of method from UITableViewDataSource called?

Comment: You mean this? http://is.gd/2Pg65L , http://is.gd/01wFAV

Comment: The first one, the key is know if the reloadData is being called or not.

Comment: sorry, i doesn't understand what you mean. can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem:

- EGORefreshTableHeaderView doesn't hide: check that the method "dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData" is called.
- The tableView doesn't reload the data: check that "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:" is called, if it does you should to reload the RSSParser.

Comment: EGORefreshTableHeaderView hide ok.

Comment: How can I reload the RSSParser?

Comment: Try calling again "start" before the [tableView  reloadData].

Comment: Like this? [self _rssParser];